# Installation of wxpython on centos

Tags: wxpython

I have installed wxpython using rpm..
Installation went good..

tried to find the rpm and finally I got rpm file for my OS as well.

python

> > > import wx
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in ?
> > >         File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/**init**.py", line 45, in ?
> > >           from wx._core import *
> > >         File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 4, in ?
> > >           import *core*
> > >       ImportError: libwx_baseu_xml-2.8.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory